# Get trending (mostPopular) channels and playlist of Youtube based on region

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

As I know we have a Youtube API to get trending youtube videos based on a region by using below API detail:

`https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list` and giving `chart=mostPopular`.

I have a similar requirement:

1). To get trending channels and playlist of youtube based on region.

2). Get users video history details.

I tried searching but couldn't get much details over it.
Please let me know if anyone worked over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`search.list`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list):

> **type**
>
> - The **type** parameter restricts a search query to only retrieve a particular type of resource. The value is a comma-separated list of resource types. The default value is **video**,**channel**,**playlist**.
>
> **regionCode**
>
> - The regionCode parameter instructs the API to return search results for the specified country. The parameter value is an [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_codes/iso_3166_code_lists/country_names_and_code_elements.htm) country code.
>
> **order**
>
> - The order parameter specifies the method that will be used to order resources in the API response. The default value is **relevance**.
> - **rating** – Resources are sorted from highest to lowest rating.

This may be the closest thing to what you want to achieve. You set `type` to `channel` or `playlist`, `regionCode` based on the region, and `order` to `rating` (closest to trending). Currently there are no  regionCode, mostPopular parameters in [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) or [Playlists: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list)

Hope this helps.

Comment: To extend this a bit, an example GET without regionCode and for channels would be `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type-channel&maxResults=50&order=rating`